# Fitting Probability distribution function in eac histogram for each bin data using matlab.....?

Tags: matlab, histogram, curve-fitting, probability-density, binning

I have x data and I did binning and created histogram of each bin.Now I want to fit the probability distribution function in each bin so I can see histogram and probability distribution function at the same graph. Here 'X' is in horizontal axis data and 'Y' represent vertical axis data of the same datasets. I have written the code below

```
 X = load data1 ; Y = load data2   
topEdge = 10; % upper limit
botEdge = 0;
numBins = 20;  


binEdges = linspace(botEdge, topEdge, numBins+1); 
[h,whichBin] = histc(X, binEdges)

% Histrogram plot of each bin

for i = 1:numBins


flagBinMembers = (whichBin == i); %Creates vector of the indices of the data entries that are in bin i
BinMean(i) = mean(power_ref(flagBinMembers)); %Calculate mean value in this bin
BinStd(i) = std(power_ref(flagBinMembers)); 
x = power_ref(flagBinMembers) - BinMean(i);
mu = power_ref(flagBinMembers)- BinMean(i); sigma =power_ref(flagBinMembers)- BinStd(i);

  figure();
 histogram(x, 'Normalization', 'pdf')
 hold on;
 Y = normpdf(x,mu,sigma);
  plot(x,Y); 
  hold off
end
```

After running this code I am not getting the fitted 'pdf' and histogram on same curve. I correctly got histogram but not 'pdf'.   Can any one suggest me or help me ....??  Thank you for your such patient for reading this !

I am getting such curve output :  [output of first bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/364bW.jpg) [Output of 2nd bin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zfxdB.jpg)

As you can see histogram and pdf not fitting. Where I am making mistake...??

Comment: you want the probabilty distribution in each bin? inside the bin they won't for sure not be normal distributed. Do you want to draw the bins and a norml distribution over all bins?

Comment: @Finn yes I want Probability distribution in each bin. Inside the bin I want to use probability distribution function because my distribution is look like Gaussian.